# Independence of kinetic energy with respect to $\rho$ when potential energy is independent of $\phi$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, differentiation

Reference material (free access right now): [Shankar](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-0576-8.pdf)

On page 81 of Shankar, (paraphrasing) he states that:

$ 1:  T$, the kinetic energy in polar coordinates, depends solely on $\frac{d}{dt} \phi$ if $\frac{d}{d \phi}V=0$, where $V$ is potential energy.
*I would like to prove this statement.*

He showed us how to calculate the polar Lagrangian, with
$$ 2: T= (1/2)m(( \frac{d}{dt}ρ )^2 + ρ^2 ( \frac{d}{dt} \phi ) ^2 ) $$ and V being some function of ρ and $\phi$ .
He subsequently proves conservation of m$ρ^2 \frac{d}{dt} \phi $ when

$\frac{d}{d \phi}$V=0

In order to prove 1, I tried showing that $$\frac{d}{dρ}T=0$$ but wind up having to show $$mρ\frac{d}{dt} \phi^2 = 0 $$ after taking the appropriate derivatives on 2. Should I just roll with that?
then I'd have to show it for other variables ($\frac{d}{dt}$ρ, for instance. I wouldn't have to show it for $\frac{d}{dt} \phi$ as a commenter pointed out), I assume.

possible other solutions: Am I misunderstanding the definition of T? Should I exploit the cyclic coordinate definition he uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence may be a bit confusing; the statement is not that $T$ is exclusively a function of $\dot{\phi}$ (which wouldn't be true, since $T = (m/2)(\dot{\rho}^2 + \rho^2 \dot{\phi^2})$), but that $T$ depends on $\dot{\phi}$ and not on $\phi$. This is what lets you conclude that $p_\phi$ is constant. But the book doesn't say anything about the dependence of $T$ on $\rho$.

Comment: his use of the word "only" definitely threw me off. In retrospect I should've considered that possibility earlier. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$T = \frac{m}{2}(\dot\rho^2+\rho^2\dot\phi^2)$, so it's always independent of $\phi$.

Comment: hello, thank you for your reply. That does eliminate one of the four possibilities. do you have any suggestions on how to prove Shankar's statement (and thus eliminate dependence on d/dt ρ and ρ alone?)